# Graph structure implementation

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I have to implement the structure as shown in the this figure:

[image: acyclic graph]

It is an unoriented acyclic graph. In the nodes there is a string variable n, on the arcs there are two variables, one integer and one of the string type.

Could anyone tell me how to implement the structure and validate nodes and arcs?

Comment: Here are my thoughts on designing a graph C++ class  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/cGraph-Class-Design

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"?

Comment: The role of StackOverflow is not for contributors to do the work for you.  Its purpose is to help you after you have attempted a possible solution but that solution is not working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Since your graph is undirected (which I take is what you mean by "unoriented") and acyclic, that means that it is a tree.

You can thus represent it as a typical doubly-linked tree: each node has a vector of shared or unique pointers to children and a raw or weak pointer back to its parent. You can store edge information paired with the child links or in a separate vector in the node.

Without more information on your use case it is impossible to answer in greater detail.